# JQuery change height of div automatically

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I have the following html structure as shown in this fiddle - 
https://jsfiddle.net/0r277q7r/4/

Some rows in the table1 are shwon and hidden on check of checkbox like this -

```
function hideshow(){
    if($('#checkShow').is(':checked')){
        $('.before').hide();
        $('.after').show();
  }else{
        $('.before').show();
        $('.after').hide();
  }
}
```

Some rows in table1 are hidden and some others are shown when you check the checkbox.

I want to change the height of table2 as and when the height of table1 changes, so that both the tables are of equal height.

What will the jquery code be like?

Thanks.

Comment: both your tables have the same `id`, `id`s should be unique

Comment: I would use https://github.com/mattbanks/jQuery.equalHeights  it works great.

Comment: @depperm: Please dont go on the nitty gritty of the details. Probably a typo. :) Updated.

Comment: @NalinAgrawal could be a typo and that could lead to bugs/problems later on, just pointing it out if OP didn't notice

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your jquery can be reduced to 2 lines with the `toggle()` function

```
function hideshow() {
    $('.before').toggle();
  $('.after').toggle();
}
```

If you give your main table an `id` say `table1` and change your 2nd table to have an `id` `table3`, then give a height to `table1` in px then change the height of `table2` and `table3` to be 100%

```js
function hideshow() {
  $('.before').toggle();
  $('.after').toggle();
}
```

```css
#table1 {
  height: 100px;
}
#table2 {
  height: 100%;
}
#table3 {
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="table1" style="border:1px solid black">
  <tr>
    <td>
      <table style="border:1px solid black" id="table2">
        <tr class="before">
          <td>some content</td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="before">
          <td>some content</td>
          <td>some other content</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>
            <input type="checkbox" id="checkShow" onclick="hideshow();" />
          </td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="after" style="display:none">
          <td>show only when check is checked</td>
        </tr>
      </table>
    </td>
    <td>
      <table style="border:1px solid black" id="table3">
        <tr>
          <td>other div2 stuff here</td>
        </tr>
      </table>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: What if I dont want to give a fixed height to parent table (table1)?

Comment: @NalinAgrawal  
`height:100%;` requires a known height from parent's CSS, else it is 100% of none

Comment: I understand that. But what if my requirement is that I can not really give a fixed height to my parent table? Will providing a min-height :100px to my parent table work? Or else, is there any other way to achieve this ?

Comment: @NalinAgrawal giving the parent table a min-height does not work, I don't know of any other way of achieving what you want

Comment: ok. I will figure something out, and post here if I find something. Thanks for this idea though.

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    $("#checkShow").on("change",function(){

        var state = $(this).prop("checked");

        if (state) {
            $('.before').hide();
            $('.after').show(); 
        }

        else {
            $('.before').show();
            $('.after').hide();

        }

    })
})
```

Final code :

```html
<html>
    <title>This is test</title>
    <head>
    </head>
    <body>
        
<table border="1">
    <tr>
        <td>
            <table style="border:1px solid black" id="table2">
                <tr class="before">
                    <td>some content</td>
                </tr>
                <tr class="before">
                    <td>some content</td>
                    <td>some other content</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td><input type="checkbox" id="checkShow"/></td>
                </tr>
                <tr class="after">
                    <td>show only when check is checked</td>
                 </tr>
                    </table>
                  </td>
                  <td>
                    <table style="border:1px solid black" id="table2">
                    <tr>
                  <td>other div2 stuff here</td>
                </tr>
                </table>
              </td>
            </tr>
            </table>
        
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script>
            
    $(document).ready(function(){

        $("#checkShow").on("change",function(){

            var state = $(this).prop("checked");

            if (state) {
                $('.before').hide();
                $('.after').show(); 
            }

            else {
                $('.before').show();
                $('.after').hide();

            }

        })
    })
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```